R - partykit, why is glmtree function creating too many partitions
I am using the glmtree function from the partykit package in R to fit a recursive partitioning logistic model. The function works as is intended, I believe it is my dataset that is the issue, I am just not certain why.
The glmtree function seemingly runs forever when I input the full model (36 variables) in the regressor variables argument. The function seems to similarly struggle with certain partitioning variables, typically those with a large spread of values and high variance. When the function does complete, it partitions the dataset into a lot of subsets, upwards of 70.
I'd like to point out that my dataset is such that predictive power of all models (logistic, random forests, etc.) is usually weak, I believe this is due to the lack of associations and relationship between most of my predictors and my response. The dataset is also large with 30,000 observations.
I am writing a dissertation and would most importantly like to know why I get so many partitions.
So far I've experimented with discrete, low variance variables and continuous variable that have a large spread, this seems to make the most difference. I've tried the full model for regressor variables and a much more parsimonious model with 5 variables and 2 to 3 partitioning variables (this one performs the best).
In terms of partitioning variables, continuous variable that have a large spread create an unmanageable number of partitions, and sometimes have the function running forever to no avail (I've had an hour straight). Low variance discrete variables work the best both in terms of predictive power of the model and number of subsets.
The model that yields the least partitions gives 18 subsets, and a very satisfactory AUC. I was however aiming for at most 7 partitions for interpretability purposes.
Could the factors that I have highlighted with my dataset (large, high variance predictors, weak associations) be responsible for this, or could I try something else to reduce the number of partitions while maintaining predictive power ? I would also like to know what the algorithm tends to struggle with, as it may apply to my dataset.
Thank you !

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
